# Following tutorial but get: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Object

Tags: node.js, express

I am following [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/vjf774RKrLc?t=964) but I am getting a problem, not sure if something has changed as the video is 2 years old.

I created a new file called posts.js

```
const express = require('express');

const router = express.Router();

router.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("We are on posts");
  });

module.express = router;
```

then in my app.js

```
const postsRoutes = require('./routes/posts')


app.use('/posts', postsRoutes);
```

yet I get `TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Object`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `module.express` to `module.exports`. You are not correctly exporting the router, thus you cannot use it properly when calling .use